# React implementing shouldComponentUpdate on my React app with loading state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm having a trouble implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` on my React app with `loadingData` state. I want to prevent component to load again when nextProps has not changed from the this.props which is working fine and it messes up `loadingData` value some how and I can't find the reason why.

Why `loadingData` ended up to be `true` even there's no change to the data in Redux(nextProps and this.props)?

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      loadingData: false,
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    const { username } = this.state
    this.setState({ loadingData: true })

    try {
      await this.props.getUserData(username)
      this.setState({ loadingData: false })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      this.setState({ loadingData: false })
    }
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.props !== nextProps
  }

render() {
  return(
    <div>{this.state.loadingData ? "Loading..." : this.props.userData}</div>
  )
}
```

Updated code to show the how I set up `loadingData` state. Some reason, adding `shouldComponentUpdate` shows, Loading... on the screen instead of userData from Redux. I'm not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

This will always return false because `this.props` is a different object than `nextProps` between each render.

For the simplest example of this:

```js
console.log({} === {}) // false
```

By default (if using `React.PureComponent`) React will perform a "shallow equality" check. It will check the equality of each prop (but will not do so recursively because of performance reasons). ([see the source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/62b04cfa753076d5ffb1d74b855f8f8db36f5186/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassComponent.js#L288)).

As a first attempt, have you tried using `React.PureComponent` in place of `React.Component`?

If that doesn't help, I would recommend sharing the entire code snippet. `shouldComponentUpdate` usually is considered a "code smell" and commonly means there's a problem with another part of the code. It should not be used as control flow, but *only* for performance optimization.

If you still must implement `shouldComponentUpdate`, [take a look at the default `shallowEqual` helper](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/a9b035b0c2b8235405835beca0c4db2cc37f18d0/packages/shared/shallowEqual.js#L19) for a bit of inspiration.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Unfortunately, `PureComponent` didn't solve my issue. I understand that `this.props !== nextProps` returns false but I still don't understand why `loadingData` state is set to true..

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should look through this.

```
var jangoFett = {
    occupation: "Bounty Hunter",
    genetics: "superb"
};

var bobaFett = {
    occupation: "Bounty Hunter",
    genetics: "superb"
};

var callMeJango = jangoFett;

// Outputs: false
console.log(bobaFett === jangoFett);

// Outputs: true
console.log(callMeJango === jangoFett);
```